# how to use system command 'grep' in perl script

Tags: perl, grep, command

I am trying to count the matching character using grep command in Perl script. Below script is counting whole directory, my desired output should contain only the count of input file not the whole directory, some one help me to do so.

```
#! use/bin/perl

use strict;


print"Enter file name for Unzip\n";
print"File name: ";
chomp(my $Filename=<>);
system("gunzip -r ./$Filename/*\n");
system('grep -c "@SRR" ./$Filename/*');
```

This is giving whole directory count.

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/q/609452/336375

Comment: Did you understand the question above??

Comment: Do you ***have*** to use the system's grep command, or you don't know how to use the `grep` command in Perl? If you don't have to use the system's grep command, why not use the one in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! use/bin/perl
use strict;
print"Enter file name for Unzip\n";
print"File name: ";
chomp(my $Filename=<>);
system("gunzip -r ./$Filename\*");
system("grep -c '\@SRR' ./$Filename\*");
```

Please let know if i misunderstood question. But above code gives us number of lines matching @SRR on zipped filename provided.

Also you don't need to unzip to count you can directly do this

```
system("zgrep -c '\@SRR' $Filename")
```

instead of

```
 system("gunzip -r ./$Filename\*");
 system("grep -c '\@SRR' ./$Filename\*");
```

Answer (score 0):

my $var=`cat filename | grep "your word"`;

Thanks,
nilesh.